Getting "No module named '_pytest'" error when I am trying to execute a pytest fixture
I installed pytest using pip install in my virtual environment and I can see it under site-packages. When I try to execute the test case, it gives me the below error :
 File "/Users/a768584/Documents/workspace/pytest-example-master/myvenv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pytest/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _pytest import __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pytest'

The pytest library folder structure looks like this :

Can someone please help me resolve this?
